# How can i slideToggle() or something of the same effect for each foreach (by knockout)?

Tags: knockout.js

Can someone tell me how can i do a effect of slide (up and down) after using foreach? I tried to applying the method of jquery but that would apply to everyone ( and for what i tried didnt do for any of them).

So, how can i slide up, or down a div when i click in each div with the name of the circuit after do the binding ?

**HTML**

'''

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-3">

    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="color:red"><b>Formula 1</b></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Circuits.html" style="color:blue"><b>Circuits</b></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Drivers.html" style="color:blue"><b>Drivers</b></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio" style="color:blue"><b>Portfolio</b></a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact" style="color:blue"><b>Contact</b></a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>

<br />

<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: list">

    <div class="flip" style="width: 50%; height: 50px; background-color:gray; margin:auto">

        <center><h5><b data-bind="text: Name">something here</b></h5></center>

        <div class="panel">Toggle</div>

    </div>
   
    <br />

</div>


<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js "></script>

<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.5.1.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.js"></script>

<script src="Circuit.js"></script>
```

'''

**JS**

'''

```
var vm = function () {

console.log('ViewModel initiated...');

var self = this;

self.baseUri = ko.observable('http://192.168.160.58/Formula1/api/Circuits');

self.list = ko.observable([]);

self.circuitsId = ko.observable([]);

self.activate = function () {

    console.log('CALL: GetCircuits...');

    var composedUri = self.baseUri()

    ajaxHelper(composedUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {

        console.log('CALL: GetCircuitsID...');

        self.list(data.List)

    });

};
self.activate()

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {

    return $.ajax({

        type: method,

        url: uri,

        dataType: 'json',

        contentType: 'application/json',

        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,

    });
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {

console.log("ready!");

ko.applyBindings(new vm());

});
```

'''

Comment: Have you read [the documentation on animated transitions](https://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html)? I think it sounds kind of like what you’re describing.